GDI+ DrawLines bug when used with Pen size more than 1
The following code:
       Graphics g(hdc);

       Pen pen1(Color(0, 0, 0), 1.0f);
       pen1.SetAlignment(PenAlignmentCenter);

       Pen pen10(Color(0, 0, 0), 10.0f);
       pen10.SetAlignment(PenAlignmentCenter);

       std::vector<Point> line1;
       line1.push_back({ 100, 100 });
       line1.push_back({ 100, 70 });
       line1.push_back({ 101, 100 });

       g.DrawLines(&pen1, line1.data(), line1.size());

       std::vector<Point> line2;
       line2.push_back({ 200, 100 });
       line2.push_back({ 200, 70 });
       line2.push_back({ 201, 100 });

       g.DrawLines(&pen10, line2.data(), line2.size());

       for (std::size_t i = 0; i < line2.size(); ++i) {
           line2[i].X += 100;
       }

       for (std::size_t i = 1; i < line2.size(); ++i)
       {
           g.DrawLine(&pen10, line2[i - 1], line2[i]);
       }

Provides the following weird results (grid, green numbers and lines are hand-drawn):

Image (1) provided as an exemplar and ruler to show where Y value 70 is, and image (2) shows the defect where the line strikes far behind the expected value. Image (3) shows that with the same data the DrawLine works fine when called in the loop.
Is it a bug or I misinterpret somehow the expected behavior of the GDI+ DrawLines?
I know that such a code is better to be placed on github, but at the moment I could share at godbolt only, so here is the full source.
It related to my previous Wrong behaviour of GDI+ DrawLines with PointF and most likely will replace it when we come to understanding of the root cause. It seems that the problem is not related to PointF, since occurs with Point, as well and related to DrawLines and Pen size.
(OS: Windows Version 10.0.19044.1889; SDK Version 10.0.26100.0)
Update
Per request from Dai in comments, I've created the GDI+ Metafile which shows correct picture for the same lines of code as it should be:


I'm unsure what you mean by "line strikes far behind"

@Dai, what wording would you prefer to describe the behaviour at image 2 when the line goes up far beyond the Y=70 ? It should stop at Y = 70 and goes to the top of the client area.

Well, it'd help if you could add axes to the image - whereas right now a white-background image on a white-background web-page doesn't help with establishing scale (also, I'm reading this on a 192dpi display, so "70px" is meaningless here, even more-so because SO is scaling the image anyway)

...but I am able to reproduce the image when I compile-and-run at my end.

@Dai, and it comes only with line2.push_back({ 201, 100 }); . If you replace it with line2.push_back({ 200, 100 }); everything would work as expected. 

@Dai, what's your Windows version? I just checked back with Windows 8 with the same result. I will check with Windows 11 and newer versions of Windows 10 a bit later today.

I'm on Windows 10 22H2. But that said, I don't see any bug here - this is how line-stroking algorithms work: DrawLine doesn't fill in a perfect rectangle for a stroke. Strokes aren't fills.

@Dai, I will make the background grey to avoid confusion with white web page. Not sure what kind of axes do you mean; something done in code or later on the screenshot with editor? You can easily see that the central line is more than twice longer than others.

Yes, because the stroke-width is so huge. The problem here is you're confusing the stroke-width with line-length - they're actually orthogonal.

@Dai, sorry, I missed the point. The question is not about the rectangle. The problem is that central line is more than two times longer than neighboring lines.

Yes, because of the stroke-width.

Could be the same reason in the Strange behaviour of GDI+ pen and drawline/drawlines, as well?

Yes - it's the same fundamental cause. You'll need to fiddle around with the pen-alignment settings when using a thick stroke width: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-setting-pen-width-and-alignment-use

That said, there is a bug in GDI+'s handling of Pens - but it's actually the opposite of what you're describing ;) "...that prevents pens of size 1.5 and below scaling correctly. It is for this reason I'm sure that all the Microsoft examples pertaining to pen scaling all have a pen width of 2."

@Dai, I’ve updated the image with the grid and values, so you can see that “overstepping” is about 50 points! It couldn’t be explained by any stroke-width. The pen-alignment was set to default which is  PenAlignmentCenter, but to ensure I put this explicitly in the code (updated); nothing has changed. I am not sure how 50 points overstep could be explained this way. I tested on Win10-latest and Win11; the image is absolutely the same. Any thoughts?

I'm unsure at this point, sorry.

@Dai, so, what kind of prove would work for you? How to do you explain 50 points overstep? And, at the end of the day stroke width is perpendicular to the line, in no way can it come this way.

I'll eat my words: I was wrong when I suggested it was the stroke-width - but I note that when you set a smaller pen size the results aren't as messed-up.

@Dai, that's exactly my point (see the title of the question). When size is more than 1 and step on one of the axis (X axis here) is not a zero, but smaller than some threshold (like half of pen size) the effect appears. It doesn't appear for Pen size 1. Seems that the bug in DrawLines when pen size more than 1. If not, what would be your explanation to see image we see. And, at the end of the day, how can I draw plots on charts if such pikes will appear everywhere if I want line width more than 1? (Of course, I could workaround with too lines, but question is what for we need such DrawLines?)

If you want to know how you should be doing 2D graphics on Windows, then the answer is simple: don't use GDI nor GDI+ - Microsoft wants us all using Direct2D now (with DirectWrite for text).

...and here's how you're meant to draw multiple lines btw.

@dai, I will try it soon. Hopefully, it doesn't have the same defect. And just to ensure you, I rewrote this code to GDI with Polyline and it works just fine with the same coordinates and pen widths. So, the problem is definitely in GDI+ if its behaviour is inconsistent with GDI in such simple things.

Can you create a GDI Metafile from your Win32/GDI+ program? That way you can open it in a tool like Illustrator and that should demystify everything.

@dai, the GDI Metafile shows the perfect result as it should be (added the image from it and the link to the source in the Update section. What this discrepancy (between image on screen and in EMF) say? As a second thought, what's you compiler and SDK version? I use VS2002 + SDK 10.0.22621.0; maybe the issue with the Gdiplus.lib (old version) or something like this? I glanced through Direct2D API, it could be used, but for small application it is too complicated, for example, when it comes to output text; I except to be forced to use wrapping libraries, etc. which is way too much...

...my only hope now is that Raymond Chen finds this post, lol.
